# Looking for a way to make a cone shaped cookie

Tags: cookies, waffle, gingerbread

I am trying to find a way to make a cross between waffle cone and fairy gingerbread. You might call it  gingerbread flavored Krumkake or Pizelle.  And if possible do it without a special waffle cone or krumkake iron.

The basic idea is to have a cookie that comes out of the oven soft and can be rolled into a cone and allowed to cool and hold it's shape.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What exactly are you asking here? Have you tried making one of those cookies that come soft out of the oven, with the added gingerbread spices?

Comment: The flavoring is not really the question here but I'm looking for advice on how to make a batter/dough that would be soft and pliable yet cool to a crisp and do it without the benefit of a press or iron. And if someone has a gingerbread recipe that fits that bill great. Otherwise yes I can adapt a recipe.

Comment: I don't know of any recipe that meets the criteria listed *without* requiring a form to roll the cone upon.

Comment: I would definitely start with a Pizelle recipe, and mold it around something like a shaker pint glass or frosting tip, depending on the size of your cookie.

Comment: The cone form I can come up with, it's the iron that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm getting a sense that making a pizelle style cookie without an iron is impossible.

Comment: It's not impossible, look here for more information: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16110/what-is-the-name-of-this-batter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the stipulation that you will need a cone form to roll the cookies on, I think the ideal cookie base for your application is the *tuile*.  You would have to adjust the flavorings, probably.  You can find many recipes by googling, such as this one from [King Arthur Flour](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/blog/2012/02/07/tuille-delicate-delicous-flowers-from-flour/).

Here is an example of [ginger-molasses tuiles](http://www.canadianliving.com/food/baking_and_desserts/ginger_molasses_tuiles.php) recipe.

Tuiles are malleable when they are hot, and can be draped over a form, or rolled around a mold or form.  When they are cool, they are very crunchy and thin and hold their shape well.

See also:  [How do you make Paillets Feuilletine?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32692/how-do-you-make-paillets-feuilletine/32955#32955)

This is an application very similar to the tuile, although much more caramlized.  That may or may not fit with your vision for the cookie you want.

Answer (score 2):

I actually tried making ice cream cones a few days ago (I thought it might be fun to go with some home made sorbet).

I was recently given [*The Perfect Scoop* by David Lebovitz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158008219X) and so I used the recipe in his book. The cone recipe he gave was similar to a tuile (I guess ice cream cones really are just a conical tuile) using egg whites, sugar, plain flour and melted butter.

He recommended using a conical mold (something like a [cream horn mold](http://www.amazon.com/s/?tag=duckduckgo-b-20&url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=cream%20horn%20mold)) but I  didn't have one so I made a mold out of a paper plate with about a 1/4 cut out then 'twisted it' to form a cone and taped it to secure, I then covered it in foil and greased it.

- [image: cone]
- [image: cone]
- [image: cone]

As for the cones, they weren't really a success as I couldn't shape them very well since they were so hot - I put 2 layers of gloves on and it still felt like I was scalding my hands handling them.

The best one looked like this:

- [image: cone]
- [image: cone]

You probably won't be able to make a cone out of ginger bread since it won't be able to go from flexible to brittle in a short amount of time (ginger bread -or at least the German *lebkuchen*- is more cake like than biscuit/cookie). However, you could add ginger bread type spices such as ginger, cinnamon, clove and maybe substitute white sugar for brown to add a toffee note to the batter.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a standard Zimtwaffel recipe, and use gingerbread spicing instead of cinnamon. Zimtwaffeln are a Palatinate specialty which is actually the type of waffle suitable for cones. Traditionally, they also have to be made in a special Zimtwaffeleisen, not a normal waffle iron, with a special kind of patterns on it, but for the cone application, I would use Sebbidychef's suggestion for shaping.

While adapted recipes for tuilles and normal cones will probably work too, I think that recipes already intended for this type of spice (and accounting for the ammount of starch present in it) will give you a better texture. This is why I would stick with Zimtwaffeln.

Comment: When I googled "Zimtwaffe" most of the responses seem to be in German... but the main reason I suggested tuiles is that they are easily made *without* special equipment, which was a desire in the question.